# Close remote connection in Midnight Commander?

Tags: mc

In the Midnight Commander I can successfully use a sh:// connection to the another computer and browse remote filesystem. But when I am finished, how to close the connection and return to the local filesystem? For now the only way I know is to exit mc. Is there a better way? Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't just going back up the directory tree leave the session / connection?

Comment: Actually, yes, that was it, up to the root and then one level more... Thanks. I usually did not work in the root dir (/), so never really saw those two magic dots... Anyway it works, but IMHO somewhat hidden functionality... I expected disconnect option in menu, but whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With info from comment I found out that when you are in the root level directory (/), there are two dots symbolizing going "up from the /", which in fact goes out from remote session.